# How to make a C++ structure contain other structure as member variable

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm wondering how to go about defining a variable in a structure that comes from another structure. For example:

```
struct Date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

struct Profile
{
    START DATE
    END DATE
    int hours_worked
    etc...
};
```

Comment: You mean something like `Date startDate;`? It works like any other type.

Comment: Perhaps you were confused about what `struct`s are? They're just classes with member visibility defaulted to public. As chris stated, think of classes and structs as custom types (such as int) that you have defined yourself.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct Profile {
    Date start;
    Date end;
    // etc...
};
```

Is that all you want?  If so I strongly recommend having a textbook on hand instead of SO being your go-to for C++ questions until you are more seasoned.  If not, please update your question.